# Book/resource recommendation for design and analysis of clinical trials

Tags: references, experiment-design, clinical-trials

I will be transitioning from a role analyzing purely observational epidemiological data to a role analyzing and designing clinical trials. I was wondering if you may have any recommendations for books to brush up on design and analysis of clinical trials?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a comprehensive overview properly informed by *history*, I recommend Stephen Senn's [Statistical Issues in Drug Development, 2nd edition](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/9780470723586/homepage/Reviews.html) [1].

1. Senn S. *Statistical Issues in Drug Development.* 2nd ed. Chichester, England ; Hoboken, NJ: John Wiley & Sons; 2007.